# Form submitted trough AJAX doesn't serialize all the components, why?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms, serialization

I have the following HTML form:

```
<form id="some_id">
    <select id="select1">...</select> // this turns in a Select2 component
    <select id="select2">...</select> // this turns in a Select2 component
    <select id="select3">...</select>
    <input type="text" name="inp1" id="inp1" />
</form>
```

I am trying to send it over AJAX as follow:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/save',
    data: $('#new_component_restriction').serialize(),
    success: function () {
        alert('form was submitted');
    }
});
```

But surprise only the input is sent on the POST request, why? I am missing something here? Do I need to get the values of the SELECT and sent along?

Comment: It's because your HTML is invalid - the `select` elements don't have any `name` attributes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the jQuery [`serialize()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

> For a form element's value to be included in the serialized string, the element must have a name attribute.

So you should add `name="something"` to all your `select` elements. It's a bit odd that it does send the 'input' element though.

Comment: The input has a `name` (I've updated the OP). That fixed the issue, thanks